# How do I merge an arrray of custom Shapes and an Array of strings into a JSON Object using the processing Java Library

Tags: java, processing, primitive-types

currently, I'm trying to make a card game. I'm using primitive shapes in Java and I want to make an object that has about 52 versions of

`id:1, suitName: hearts, Cardnum: 1`

the error I'm getting when using the processing interface states

`Cannot find a class or type named “Array”`

the set up for my code looks as such

```
      PShape[] suits = new PShape[4];
                 // An array of PShapes
      size(640, 360);
  
      PShape[ ] suits; //Declare Array

      suits[0] = loadShape("diamond.svg");
      suits[1] = loadShape("heart.svg");
      suits[2] = loadShape("spade.svg");
      suits[3] = loadShape("club.svg");

      String[] allCards;
      String[] cards = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

      int numCards;
      int suitCards;
```

the for loop for processing and building the deck of cards

```
   for( suitCards=0 ;suitCards<5 ; suitCards++){
       JSONObject ALlCards = new JSONObject();
       ALlCards.setInt("id", i);
       ALlCards.setString("suitName", suits[i]);
       ALlCards.setString("CardNumber", cards[i]);
       ALlCards.setJSONObject(i, ALlCards);
   }

System.out.println(ALlCards);
```

I tried setting up an array initially by using first by

```
    PShape diamond, heart, spade, club;

    suits.add(diamond = loadShape("diamond.svg"));
```

but I got the same error. But I'm under the impression that I believe
`suits[0] = loadShape("diamond.svg");`
this method works just as well

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation on adding primitive images in processing, it is the same as adding primitive shapes in processing. [enter link description here](https://processing.org/examples/requestimage.html)

you need to convert your primitive images into integers by finding the count of the images. So if I have 4 suits I need to establish that count.
pass the count to the primitive object

'''
int suitCount = 4;
PShape[] suits = new PShape[suitCount];
'''

```
  then you can add the shapes to the object.
```

'''

```
void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  
  suits[0] =  loadShape("diamond.svg");
  suits[1]  = loadShape("hearts.svg");
  suits[2] = loadShape("spades.svg");
  suits[3] = loadShape("clubs.svg");
  System.out.print(suitCount);
}
```

'''

when you console out the suitCount you will get 4 suits.